# Find out the parent view of a clicked button in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have some code where I have 3 buttons and I would like to find out the parent view of those buttons when clicked

```
 @IBAction func resizeButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    if(sender.isEqual(resizeButton)) {
        //This is to convert to small square
    } else if(sender.isEqual(maximizeButton)) {
        //This is to convert to maximized view
    } else if(sender.isEqual(closeButton)) {
        //This is to close the view completely

    }
}
```

Now I can identify the sender button but how do I identify the view this button is sitting in?

Thank you

Nikhil

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Please try the following

```
sender.superview
```

Answer (score 2):

I you don't want to create a custom class and also don't want to use accessibilityHin:

```
    func performAction(_ sender : AnyObject?)
{
    let cell = sender?.superview??.superviewOfClassType(UITableViewCell.self) as! UITableViewCell
    let tbl = cell.superviewOfClassType(UITableView.self) as! UITableView
    let indexPath = tbl.indexPath(for: cell) 
    let myData = myDataArray[indexPath.row]
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a specific parent in the view hierarchy or even in the parent controllers or any other responder, you can use this extension:

```
extension UIResponder {
    func nextFirstResponder(where condition: (UIResponder) -> Bool ) -> UIResponder? {
        guard let next = next else { return nil }
        if condition(next) { return next }
        else { return next.nextFirstResponder(where: condition) }
    }
}
```

#### Usage Example

The following returns the `tableViewController` that contains `myButton`. No matter how deep it is nested in views and subviews.

```
let tvc = myButton.nextFirstResponder { $0 is UITableViewController }
```